# Trouble on Debian boot up "Timed out waiting for device dev-disk..."

Tags: debian, filesystems, boot, disk, system-recovery

I can't boot my Debian 9.5 with following errors. If I remember correctly ACPI Errors were shown every time I turn on PC. But computer always boot right with these errors, so I didn't care much. The new error starts at "A start job is running.."

[image: error 1st part]

[image: error 2nd part]

When did the error start?
I was going to sell my older HDD so I erased the disk `/dev/sdd` via command `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdd bs=1M`. The disk was mounted to `/diskB_1TB`. After erasing the HDD I turned down computer and then disconnected the disk from a motherboard. After that I turned on the computer but the error occured for the first time.

I've tried procedure from: https://askubuntu.com/questions/924170/error-on-ubuntu-boot-up-recovering-journal/924335?noredirect=1#comment1512824_924335
but it fixed nothing.

[image: tried commands]

I have 4 disks

- /dev/sda with windows
- /dev/sdb with linux debian
- /dev/sdc as 2TB data disk
- /dev/sdd as 1TB data disk (the former disk I erased and disconnected)

[image: my disks]

Is there anything I can still do in this situation? I'm pretty sure I did delete only `/dev/sdd` disk. I can still access data (via terminal) located in `/dev/sdc` and in `/deb/sdb` where my `/home/stepaiv3` is located. Moreover I can normally boot into my windows on `/dev/sda`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Systemd assumes certain mounts are critical to the system and as such a failure to mount one results in it switching to emergency mode.

Systemd should have reconfigured its automount units when the device was disconnected unless it appears in /etc/fstab or you configured it as a mount unit. So the issue is likely that you still have /diskB_1TB in your fstab.

From your emergency mode console try editing your fstab `/etc/fstab` and remove the line with `/diskB_1TB` then reboot.

Comment: Wow.... it was that easy! :D Thank you so much. After removing the line from /etc/fstab my Debian boot :)

Comment: Good call. The bigger problem is that often this issue is not logged at all.